# Looking for nested object existance

Tags: grails

```
class Car {
    String carname
}

class Factory {
    Car car
    String factoryname
}
```

How can I check if an object `Factory` with `factoryname == "Kia"`, `carname == "newmodel"` exists?

Comment: Everything is perfect,thanks.

Comment: could you please verify, that the "everything is perfect, thanks" comment is you basically saying, that you found your own solution? if so mind to add it as an answer?

Comment: @cfrick I think he refferred to the edit. :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use **createCriteria()** method and **alias**.

```
def cName = 'newmodel'
def fName = 'Kia'
def objects = Factory.createCriteria().count() {
    createAlias('car', 'c'),
    eq('c.carname', cName)
    eq('factoryname', fName)
}
boolean isThere = objects
```

Comment: just use `count()` - saves you, hibernate, and the db the trouble of fetching throwaway data

Comment: @cfrick oh yes. I changed structure of my answer on the way and forgot to switch back the code fully! Edited.

Comment: I cringe when I see `? true : false`. It would be simpler to change that last line to `boolean isThere = objects`. You have permission to use types and not declare everything as `def`.